# Draw a transparent box on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do you make a transparent box like the one for the PDF viewer that shows the page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a plain view (or UILabel with the text), then set `view.layer.cornerRadius` and `view.backgroundColor` and `view.alpha` to your liking.

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be this easy